# How to make sidebar files manager in html ace editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, ace-editor

I want to make **sidebar file manager** like html IDE'S where we can surf our internal storage and open files and edit files on editor. I am working on a **ace editor**.so I want a file explorer in sidebar and it should open in my ace editor.( it is not a tabbed editor with tabs ...It is just a simple ace editor. You can use any  **Cordova plugin**.
How can I do that ?please help!

Comment: Hi, please provide some snippets of code  you've tried to write

Comment: I'am sorry ..!! Actually I didn't tried yet because it was .....I don't have much idea about it how to do that . If you know you can tell from beginning or just you can tell the ways how can I do that ..! Thanks for you response ❤️❤️

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a place for plain “how can I do that” questions.

Comment: Ok as you say . I just learning web development from 8 months . So there are chances for many mistakes with that. All okay !